# Alias for EditorAttribute

Tags: c#, attributes

Is there a way to create a shorter alias for an EditorAttribute? Instead of:

```
    [EditorAttribute(typeof<ColorPickerDialogPropertyValueEditor>, typeof<DialogPropertyValueEditor>)]
    public Color4 Color { get; set; }
```

I would like to write:

```
    using ColorPicker = EditorAttribute(typeof<ColorPickerDialogPropertyValueEditor>, typeof<DialogPropertyValueEditor>)
    [ColorPicker]
    public Color4 Color { get; set; }
```

Unfortunately the EditorAttribute class is sealed so I cannot inherit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see only one way:

```
using CPDPEditor = YourNamespace.ColorPickerDialogPropertyValueEditor;
using DPEditor = YourNamespace.DialogPropertyValueEditor;
```

...

```
[Editor(typeof(CPDPEditor), typeof(DPEditor))]
```

Or maybe the `AttributeProvider` will help you (dont know how)