# How to not lose method attribute in stack trace due to inlining?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to use an attribute on a method to provide information to another method down the call-chain. I do this by examining the stack trace. My experimental results show, that the method carrying the attribute can get inlined and the attribute lost.

I am asking for elegant ways to write code that would add the attribute and at the same time prevent loss of that attribute, even at a cost of not inlining the method carrying the attribute.

I know I could use `MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)` alongside my custom attribute to be safe, but I'd rather not do that, as the attribute is used in many places and it would be "manual coupling" and therefore error-prone.

I don't know if pre-processor macro wouold be elegant solution? Can it be easily shared in the whole project?

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41583607/1902651) to another question, I found the idea of writing a Roslyn plugin to do this for me. I'd like to avoid that, but it is probably the most elegant solution so far.

I had an idea of my attribute inheriting `MethodImpl`, but that's sadly `sealed`.

This is my minimal example on which I'm experimenting.

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
sealed class A : Attribute { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    M();
}

[A]
static void M()
{
    PrintStack();
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
static void PrintStack()
{
    foreach (var frame in new StackTrace().GetFrames())
    {
        var method = frame.GetMethod();
        Console.WriteLine($"{method.Name} ({method.GetCustomAttributes(true).FirstOrDefault()?.GetType().Name})");
    }
}
```

In debug build it prints:

```
PrintStack ()
M (A)
Main ()
```

In release build it prints:

```
PrintStack ()
Main ()
```

I'm looking for a solution that either preserves the whole `M (A)` row or at least just the `A` attribute somewhere (maybe at the `Main` method).

Comment: If you don't want `M` being inlined, you'd have to add `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` on `M`, but... in general, you shouldn't *need* to know the details of what your call path is ... calling `GetFrames()` etc is *not* something you should usually be doing (caveats exist)